# how to do live camera object detection in python

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, detection, opencv

I have the code:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cvlib as cv
from cvlib.object_detection import draw_bbox
im = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\logos\normal.png')
bbox, label, conf = cv.detect_common_objects(im)
output_image = draw_bbox(im, bbox, label, conf)
plt.imshow(output_image)
plt.show()
```

That detects most objects in the picture, but I want to be able to make it from live video, I tried using `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` but I could not get it to work.

Comment: You will have to give more information about the way in which it is not working. Does it throw an error? Do you get a completely black image? Have you tried a video file? What is your setup? What hardware?

Comment: hi, i should of been more specific about this question, i would prefer it to be live, but i guess i could use a video file if i really had to, with this code cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
        
    ##    im = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\logos\imagetodetect.jpg')
    bbox, label, conf = cv.detect_common_objects(frame)
    output_image = draw_bbox(frame, bbox, label, conf)
    plt.imshow(output_image)
    plt.show()
    plt.clf() when i run this it shows me only one frame then ends the program, thanks. im using 3.5.0 python

Comment: srry for formating could not get it to format corectly

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dk9lP5iHGb0kzOK79ofmQuJDZ5HqvubN/view?usp=sharing                                                                                       there is the file in drive to see so it is formated correctly

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Can you put your first comment into the question for posterity?

Answer (score 1):

A typical program executes every line until it's done, and then exits. Your code asks it to open a stream and show a frame. Then, because it's done everything that you've asked it to do, it exits.

In the code you provided in the comments, you are using matplotlib's `.clf()` immediately after `.show()`, which will clear the figure and potentially is the cause of your issue. You should be using `cv2.imshow()` instead.

If you want it to remain open, you need to put your displaying code inside a `while True` loop as shown in the [getting started part of the docs](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html). Combining their code with yours, you would get something like (however I haven't tested it):

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
import cvlib as cv
from cvlib.object_detection import draw_bbox

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Detect objects and draw on screen
    bbox, label, conf = cv.detect_common_objects(frame)
    output_image = draw_bbox(im, bbox, label, conf)

    cv2.imshow('output',output_image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

For a webcam, this will keep going until you press q to interrupt the program.

Be warned, this may not run smoothly because object detection models are typically fairly computationally expensive. But that is a challenge for another question.